# strcat() vs sprintf() inside a loop

Tags: c, performance, loops, printf, strcat

I have a program that's removes every variables inside a string. Theses variables start with '$'. So, for, example, if I give a string like [1,2,$1,$2], it should return just [1,2].

However, which loop is better for perfomance?

This:

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (*token != '$')
    {
        sprintf(dst, "%s,%s", dst, token);
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "], ");
}
```

or this:

```
while (token != NULL)
{
    if (*token != '$')
    {
        strcat(dst, token);
        strcat(dst, ",");
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "], ");
}
```

Comment: I have my doubts about using two strcats because it will go twice to the end of my dst string, and sprintf will just override it once.

Comment: Apart from the sprintf method invoking undefined behaviour (which BTW includes "apparently working fine"), (see answer below) the sprintf function is quite complicated and it is probably slower that the strcat approach. OTH you should evaluate if it is worth to optimize this.

Comment: Neither.  As mentioned by Eugene, the first one is undefined behavior, so it's out.  The second is a textbook case of Schlemiel The Painter. 
https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `strtok` is destructive, so the input string will not be usable after this code is executed. That being the case, you might as well do the transformation in place. This has a couple of advantages, one of which being that you do not need to allocate any memory (because the final string cannot be longer than the original string). This also requires a little bit of extra bookkeeping, but that provides another advantage: the resulting function's execution time is linear in the size of the input. Restarting the scan of the output buffer from the beginning on each iteration -- as both of your solutions do -- makes the function *quadratic* in the length of the string. [Note 1] The use of a quadratic algorithm is much more serious than minor differences in the cost of alternative standard library calls.
2. As various people have mentioned, it is Undefined Behaviour to call `sprintf` in such a way that there is overlap between the output buffer and one of the strings to be printed. So your usage of `sprintf` is incorrect even though it might appear to work on some implementation.
3. Neither `strcat` nor `sprintf` protects you from buffer overflow. You could use `snprintf` (by placing the new string at the end of the accumulated buffer, instead of overwriting the beginning of the buffer with itself on each iteration) or you could use `strncat`, but in both cases you'd need to do some extra bookkeeping.

So here's a quick implementation of the algorithm proposed in the first point. Note that it does not call `malloc()` nor does it allocate any string on the stack. Also note that it uses `memmove` rather than `memcpy` to move the newly-discovered token forward in the string in order to avoid problems if the token and its destination were to overlap. (`memmove` allows an overlap; `memcpy`, `strcpy` and `strcat` do not.)

```
/* Compresses the string str in place by removing leading and trailing separator
 * characters (which are the characters in 'fs') and replacing any interior
 * sequence of separator characters with a single instance of 'ofs'.
 * Returns 'str'.
 */
char* compress(char* str, const char* fs, char ofs) {
  char* out = str;
  char* token = strtok(str, fs);
  while (token != NULL) {
    size_t tlen = strlen(token);
    memmove(out, token, tlen);
    out += tlen;
    *out++ = ofs;
    token = strtok(NULL, fs);
  }
  /* Overwrite the last delimiter (if there was one) with a NUL */
  if (out != str) --out;
  *out = 0;
  return str;
}
```

#### API notes:

- Unlike the original, this does not discard tokens starting with a `$`. That would be trivial to add.
- Also unlike the original, this function goes to the trouble of avoiding a trailing `,`. Again, that would be easy to change if there were a good reason. (However, the trailing comma means that strings with just one token will end up being one character longer, so the in-place guarantee can't be made.)
- I chose to return the address of the start of the compressed string (which is the same as the address of the input buffer) to be consistent with various standard C interfaces. However, in many cases it would be more useful to return `out` (which is the address of the trailing NUL), in order to allow further concatenation without having to compute the new length of the string. Alternatively, one could return the new length of the string, as `sprintf` does (`return out - str;`)
- This API is honest about the fact that it destroys the original string (by overwriting it with the transformed one); functions which simply call `strtok` on their input but return a separate output can cause subtle bugs because it is not obvious to the caller that the original string is destroyed. While it is not possible to restore a string after `strtok` has been called on it, it is easy to convert an in-place algorithm into a non-destructive algorithm, by simply copying the original string:

  ```
  /* Returns freshly allocated memory; caller is responsible for freeing it */
  char* compress_and_copy(const char* str, const char* fs, char ofs) {
    return compress(strdup(str), fs, ofs);
  }
  ```
- It's of course possible that the original unsimplified function did not have the feature that it was guaranteed to produce a shorter string; for example, it might be expanding segments starting with a `$` by replacing them with the value of a variable. In this case, it would be necessary to produce a new string.

  In some cases, maybe even most cases, the output will still be shorter than the input. But one should resist the temptation to do the transformation in place if possible and allocate a new string only if necessary. Although it might be more efficient, it complicates the rules for allocation ownership; you end up having to say "caller owns the returned string only if it is different from the original string", which is clumsy and accident-prone.

  So if that's the actual use case, the optimal solution (from the perspective of clean API design) is to use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to non-destructively walk the original string. That's a little more work, because it needs even more bookkeeping; on the other hand, it avoids the need to recompute `strlen(token)` after the token has been identified.

#### Notes:

1. Technically, the time is proportional to the product of the length of the string and the number of tokens, but in the worst case (where the tokens are short) this is effectively O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Good analysis and proposal. Note however that the output can be one byte longer than the input, so the array pointed to by `str` must be large enough for the worst case: a single very long word.

Comment: @chqrlie: the comma placed at the end of a single word goes on top of the NUL and then is overwritten by a NUL at the end. Intermediate results are not NUL-terminated. So it doesn't require any exra space.

Comment: Good point. the `*out++ = ofs;` threw me off. I personally would probably move the test before the `memmove` and only insert the `','` before the second and subsequent tokens. The output is the same, no backtracking required at the expense of one extra (cheap) test per token.

Comment: @chqrlie: to each their own :-) I find this logic clearer but we all have our own styles. For the record, *ofs++ is legit even if ofs points at the NUL; it's a one-past-the-end pointer to the array.

Answer (score 6):

According to [C11 standard 7.21.6.6 p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6p2), describing `sprintf`:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So your first snippet is invoking an undefined behavior as it is copying from `dst` to `dst`. The `strcat` approach does not have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Neither approach is palatable:

- passing `sprintf` the same pointer as the destination and the source for a `%s` format specifier has undefined behavior. Furthermore, `sprintf` cannot prevent buffer overflow if the destination array is not large enough.
- the second approach with a couple of `strcat` calls has the potential buffer overflow issue and is inefficient as the destination string is scanned repeatedly to find the location for the copy.

Here is an alternate approach:

```
char src[LINE_SIZE];
char dst[LINE_SIZE + 1];  /* dst is large enough for the copy */
int pos = 0;

token = strtok(src, "], ");
while (token != NULL) {
    if (*token != '$') {
        pos += sprintf(dst + pos, "%s,", token);
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "], ");
}
```